# Maven copies dependencies in project structure

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies

In one project of mine maven for some reason copies all the needed dependencies into the project structure itself - next to the folders src, target, etc. - even though the dependencies are already existing in the .m2 repository folder.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to disable this?

I am using Zulu 11 JDK.

My POM File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.telekom</groupId>
    <artifactId>subscriberservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>subscriberservice</name>
    <description>Callbackservice for horizon Events</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Without the pom file and how it looks like it's hard to say? Not even knowing are you building on plain command line which versions of Maven, JDK, etc. you are using?

Comment: @khmarbaise I added the infos in the Question

Comment: Can you explain this: `copies all the needed dependencies into the project structure itself ` more in detail? apart from that within the pom file this don't make sense like using `gson` .. spring boot uses jackson so why not stick with jackson? Also hibernate validator using a specific version ?  Also you should use `spring-boot-starter-security` instead of using specific versions (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise that means that all the dependencies are copied into the project. Next to the src, target, etc. folders there are for example the folders io, de, com, commons-codec, commons-io, junit, javax, net, org, and so on.

Comment: @Mars Maybe you somehow specific the project dir as local repository?

Answer (score 0):

If I take the pom as given and call Maven like the following:

```
mvn clean package
```

I will get the following tree:

```
$ tree                                                                                                                                                                                          
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- target
    |-- maven-archiver
    |   `-- pom.properties
    |-- subscriberservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    `-- subscriberservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original

2 directories, 4 files
```

No copying of artifacts at all??